# Substituting a Value into an Expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica so pardon me for the elementary question.

Can some one kindly explain that what is happening in the simple code below?

The `With` command does not work in the first case but it works in the second one. I don't understand why this happens.

[image]

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the desired result by evaluating the expression within `With` using

```
    With[{y = 1}, Evaluate[g]]
    (*10*)
```

Alternatively you can directly substitute any value $y$ in the expression using `ReplaceAll`

```
    g /. y -> 1
    (*10*)
```

Comment: Or, define g with set delayed rather than set: `g:=y^2+5 y + 4`

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the nice guide. And what is the reason that the above does not work?

Comment: @H.R. see below ;-) Marchi was a few seconds faster than me...

Answer (score 4):

The With command has the attribute "HoldAll", so g is not evaluated. You can force evaluation with

```
With[{y = 1}, Evaluate @ ReleaseHold @ g]
```

but the more easy ways is to do

```
g /. y -> 1
```

Or simply define a function of y (which is probably what you want):

```
f[y_] := y^2 + 5 y + 4
```

then simply f[1] gives what you want.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the answer. I knew about defining pure functions but I wanted to know the other way. :) Your answer was useful in the sense that it released that why my code was not working. The problem was the attribute `HoldAll`.